# Append `return false;` to `onClick` event handler in JavaScript

Tags: jquery

**Main Problem** : Get rid of `#` when user clicks on `anchor` tag. I found a solution for this, which is adding `return false;` in `onClick` handler

**Secondary Problem** : My current code looks like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="javaScript:toggleDisplay();" title="Some Title">
    @ViewBag.TotalRecords
</a>
```

And according to solution I got, I want it like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="javaScript:toggleDisplay();return false;" title="Some Title">
    @ViewBag.TotalRecords
</a>
```

- How can I append `return false;` to my javaScript function call? I can do it manually, but is there any easy way to do this. I am using jQuery?
- Is there any other way to get rid of `#`, without modifying the current markup?

**EDIT**

`@ViewBag.TotalRecords`: This is a MVC3 ASP.Net thing, but it is not related to the question, hence I didn't put it in the tags.

Thanks

Comment: can you explain your question a little more?

Comment: `onclick="javaScript:toggleDisplay();"` It is not an error, but the `javaScript:` prefix is probably not doing what you think it is.

Comment: @Shaheer, if I use my first code snippet, my `toggleDisplay()` function works properly, but I get `#` in my Query String. If I do `toggleDisplay(); return false;` it is not there.

Comment: you get `#` in the query string and the page probably scrolls to the top.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure perhaps you can write return false in your function call?

Comment: Using [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) would solve your problem and make your application much more maintainable

Comment: Downvoter, please provide reason. +1 @Thilo, I haven't face this issue in my current app, but yes in other it happens.

Comment: @Shaheer, I can do this but again as I mentioned in the question, I will have to edit my code every where. :(

Comment: in how many places have you defined your function? it must be at one single place...

Comment: I have around 18 pages, and every page has around 4-8 anchor tags :)

Comment: @Phil, will check your solution.

Comment: is your function defined on all of these pages or one javascript file?

Comment: @Shaheer, Some are inline with the pages, some are in js files.

Comment: then you will have to do some re-factoring, it is a bad design, put your function in one single js file and then call that file over there, it will help you a lot in the future and specially in the cases like this :)

Comment: @Phil, yes it is in my queue, but currently I'm working on almost 3 projects, so priorities changed :)

Comment: Thanks @Phil, got my solution from your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil), as I said got something out of it. Got not one but two solutions.

If I add following code to js File, all `click` handlers are handled (will make it specific for `anchor` later on)

Using plain JavaScript ([Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript))

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Using jQuery

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

The jQuery Solution is little different than the one suggested by [elclanrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670396/elclanrs), in the sense, if I do `$('a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`, it works for `anchor`, but I modify my DOM and add new `anchor` to it, click on this anchor causes `#` in query string.

**EDIT**

The above solution causes all the clicks to go through the handler, even which I don't want. Because of this normal `anchor` with `href` as url were not working, so this is the **working solution**

```
$("a").live("click", function (e) {
   if ($(this).attr("href") != "#") return;
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
});
```

Hope this helps some one else.

Answer (score 4):

You really shouldn't use an `a` tag for this -- it's not acting as a link; it's acting as a javascript button. You can use CSS to style it to look like a link if you want to, but semantically it is not an anchor. Consider using `<span class="toggle-display-button"></span>` or similar instead. This will also get rid of the unwanted side effect of scrolling to the top of the page and appending `#` to the URL that you're experiencing now.

It's also bad practice to put javascript in your markup like that. You can bind the event directly to the element using jQuery's [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method; this is cleaner and more flexible should you decide to change how the page looks or works in the future.

Comment: Why `<span>` and not `<button>`?

Comment: I can do lots of stuff, but almost everything (90%) will end up in modifying my markup or javascript function, which I don't want. So if you have anything in that 10%, it will help me.

Comment: @Phil - It's just harder to make a `button` look like a link in CSS (assuming that's desired). `span` was the lazy man's choice.

Comment: @Amar - You want a solution that doesn't involve modifying your javascript or markup? What exactly are you hoping to modify?

Comment: I can not modify my javaScript functions to include `return false` nor I can modify my `onclick` code which I have in question statement. I need some solution, which when I put in my js script will handle the situation, @Phil, has suggested Unobtrusive JavaScript, I'm checking that now.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure Implementing an unobtrusive solution would require you to rewrite most / all of your HTML and JavaScript but you'd be happier for it

Comment: @IanHenry Styling buttons is easy :) Just remove the borders and background color

Comment: @Phil, still will check what is this. Atleast will learn something out of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot alter your html, or the way you hook up the click event, you can always block the click from going through (which is what causes the url to be updated with #):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    if ('#' == $(this).attr('href'))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

You really should refactor though, 18 pages is not much.  With a good IDE, it should be quick.

Comment: +1 This is closes and prefect solution, I got. Thanks. And yes, I could have done the editing stuff, but now at least I learn something new :) Because of this I learned `closest`, `document.addEventListener` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you know how to use jQuery? `#` means empty link, you don't get rid of it...

```
$('a').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: I am not using jQuery to bind my javascript function.

Comment: You can also simply use `$("a").click(function(){return false;});`

Comment: how does the new jQuery click handler work together with the existing `onclick` in the markup (that he does not want to change)?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why would you want to use `onclick`?

Comment: I would not, but OP says he is not using jQuery to bind the functions, and he does not want to (or cannot?) change the markup.

Comment: @elclanrs, Yes I know jQuery (you can check my profile), and got my own solution too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, well...It didn't seem so looking at the question. Glad you solved it!