# JQuery smooth scroll doesn't work in practice

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, anchor

I have a problem with a smooth scrolling self-included jQuery `function` this is what I want to obtain, a simple smooth scroll effect

```js
// GLOBAL JS
(function($){

  var $body,
      $window,
      settings = {
        duration: 3000
      };

  // Smooth scrolling
  function smoothScrool (event) {
    var $this = $(this),
        href = $this.attr('href'),
        $target = $(href);

        if ($target.length > 0) {
          
          event.preventDefault();

          $body.animate({
            scrollTop: $target.offset().top
          }, settings.duration);
        }
  }

  function bindings (){

    // Smooth scroll function
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', smoothScrool);

  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Variabili
    $body = $('html, body');
    $window = $(window);

    bindings();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.long {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
  }

.red {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#hello">this goes to HELLO</a>
<a href="#hello" class="red">this is red and goes to HELLO</a>
<div class="long"></div>
<div id="hello" class="prova"> here is hello </div>
```

For some reason I can't have it [here](http://tryout.campitura.it/). Can someone please explain me what I missed please, the syntax of the links is basically the same i just added `class`es and `section`s which I think shouldn't bother the script.

Thank you

Comment: You need to explain what the issue is i.e. what is the error you are getting? (I assume you are getting an error because you say 'I can't have it here')

Comment: The fact is that I have no errors, it just wont work, the exactly same js works in the snippet here

Comment: Have you looked at the 'dev tool' console in FireFox? and it reports nothing?

Comment: I assumed was a html problem but the html anchors work, the syntax is the same I have used here

Comment: Yeah, its clear you can check by yourself the link to the full context is this: [link](http://tryout.campitura.it/)

Comment: Hmm bizzare... might I suggest that you look at http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I would like to avoid bootstrap

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with the default operation of an anchor in a href... have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222907/append-return-false-to-onclick-event-handler-in-javascript for suggestions on how to prevent it... not sure why it doesn't work in the site though.

Comment: The anchor syntax seems correct and coherent to the question you posted